# Apex Rest Webservice is not working as documented in Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide V34.0

Tags: apex, force.com, apexrest

I have two Apex Rest Webservice Rest1 & Rest2.

Rest1 webservice Apex class has annotation `@RestResource(urlMapping='/ApexRest/')`

Rest2 webservice Apex class has annotation `@RestResource(urlMapping='/ApexRest/*')` which is saved last.

But when I tried to call the Apex Rest webservice using url `url/service/apexrest/ApexRest` it calls Rest1 not Rest 2 which is last saved. So I am getting confused, Is salesforce documentation is right?

**An extract from Page No: 255 Force.com Apex Code Developer's Guide V34.0 summer'15 documentation:**

> The URL patterns URLpattern and URLpattern /* match the same URL. If
>   one class has a urlMapping of URLpattern and another class has a
>   urlMapping of URLpattern /*, a REST request for this URL pattern
>   resolves to the class that was saved last.

Answer (score 0):

The base URL and the urlMapping value form the URI that the client sends in a REST request. In this case, the URL mapping contains the asterisk wildcard character, which means that the resource URI can contain any value after /Apexrest/.

In your web service you are using the url(url/service/apexrest/ApexRest), which by defaults calls the rest1. To avoid confusions have proper url mapping values for both rest 1 and rest 2, like @RestResource(urlMapping='/Rest1/*')

Comment: I can choose the option to change the url mapping name so that there is no more confusion. But I want to know the reason why this is not as documented in salesforce or may be I  am wrong here?

Comment: If you want to call Rest you may need to use url/service/apexrest/ApexRest. For calling Rest 2 you may need to use url/service/apexrest/ApexRest/. The '/' at the end determines to call Rest2 or not. I am not 100% sure, but this what the I understood from documentation

Comment: Please look at the question again and tell me which will execute first Rest1 or Rest2? Rest1 url is url/service/apexrest/ApexRest/. For calling Rest 2 url is url/service/apexrest/ApexRest/* .